# How can I convert a color image to grayscale in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, colors, image-manipulation, grayscale

I am trying to implement an algorithm in computer vision and I want to try it on a set of pictures.  The pictures are all in color, but I don't want to deal with that.  I want to convert them to grayscale which is enough for testing the algorithm.

How can I convert a color image to grayscale?

I'm reading it with:

```
x = imread('bla.jpg');
```

Is there any argument I can add to `imread` to read it as grayscale?  Is there any way I change `x` to grayscale *after* reading it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use `rgb2gray` to strip hue and saturation (ie, convert to grayscale).  [Documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2gray.html)

Comment: They really need to stop moving the documentation. :)

Answer (score 8):

```
x = imread('bla.jpg');
k = rgb2gray(x);
figure(1),imshow(k);
```

Comment: >> k = rgb2gray(im);
Undefined function 'rgb2gray' for input arguments of type 'uint8'.

Answer (score 2):

I found this link:
http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2007/07/20/imoverlay-and-imagesc/
it works.

it says:

```
im=imread('your image');
m=mat2gray(im);
in=gray2ind(m,256);
rgb=ind2rgb(in,hot(256));
imshow(rgb);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can using this code:

```
im=imread('your image');
k=rgb2gray(im);
imshow(k);
```

using to matlab

Answer (score 1):

```
I=imread('yourimage.jpg');
p=rgb2gray(I)
```

Comment: I know that the answer is simple, but code-only answers are discouraged here. Please add a little context, explain what `rgb2gray` does and maybe link to the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `imread()` and `rgb2gray()` functions to get a gray scale image.

Example:

```
I = imread('input.jpg');
J = rgb2gray(I);
figure, imshow(I), figure, imshow(J);
```

If you have a color-map image, you must do like below:

```
[X,map] = imread('input.tif');
gm = rgb2gray(map);
imshow(X,gm);
```

The `rgb2gray` algorithm for your own implementation is :

```
f(R,G,B) = (0.2989 * R) + (0.5870 * G) + (0.1140 * B)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Color Image**

[image: Color Image]

**Gray Scale image**

[image: Gray Scale image]

```
  bg = imread('C:\Users\Ali Sahzil\Desktop\Media.png');  // Add your image 
  redChannel = bg(:, :, 1);
  greenChannel = bg(:, :, 2);
  blueChannel = bg(:, :, 3);
  grayImage = .299*double(redChannel) + .587*double(greenChannel) 
  +.114*double(blueChannel);
  imshow(grayImage);
```

Comment: Is this a better solution than using the built-in `rgb2gray`?

Comment: Yeah, it is completely fine to use the build-in function but doing thing manual gives you a better understanding of how a grayscale image is generated.